# Dual OS boot issue

Tags: rhel, windows, uefi, bios

I have Asus motherboard which has UEFI BIOS and have 2 hard disk. I installed Windows 10 OS earlier on first Hard disk and it is working as expected. I checked that even though I had UEFI , I had earlier used Legacy BIOS on UEFI with SecureBoot enabled. This was done a year ago. This first hard disk is MBR partitioned.

Now I am trying to install RHEL 7 OS on my second Hard disk. This second hard disk is also MBR partitioned and I formatted this Hard disk as 2 partition, one with NTFS file system and other as EXT4 File system and I installed RHEL 7 on this EXT 4 filesystem. (By manually partitioning during RHEL 7 installation process)

Now after the installation, I was not able to see any GRUB Boot loader option and simply, my computer enters into Windows 10 OS always.

So I used my RHEL 7 OS installation disk and boot into this DVD disk and logged on to rescue mode and I check this folder "/sys/firmware/efi" . As this folder exists, I am guessing, My RHEL OS is installed as UEFI partition(GPT) but nonetheless, I removed this RHEL 7 OS installation disk and I booted my computer and It went into Windows 10 OS. Now, I went into diskmgmt.msc and saw that the second hard disk is also partitioned as MBR only.

I reformatted my second hard disk again and need help on the below

1. I have Asus ROG Strix B 450 Motherboard with UEFI BIOS that support Legacy BIOS called as CSM -Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which is enabled by default. It makes the motherboard actually look like a BIOS system, allowing it to boot from NTFS and MBR disk.
2. I have installed Windows 10 OS and my boot options on my UEFI says to boot from both "UEFI and Legacy OPROM". If I change this to only "UEFI Driver", even my windows 10 OS is not getting loaded which I guess, my Windows 10 OS had been installed as Legacy BIOS with MBR.

Question A: Should I change my Windows 10 OS installation from MBR to GPT (for enabling Dual BOOT OS with RHEL)

Question B: Should I change my second hard disk (this is now in un-allocated state as deleted this partition) from MBR to GPT (for enabling Dual BOOT OS with RHEL)

Question C: My first hard disk which contains Windows OS 10, has 4 partitions (C,D,E,F) and I have installed Windows 10 OS on C: drive. If I install RHEL 7 on my second hard disk. should I install linux GRUB/Boot loader on this C: drive on my first hard disk?

Question D: If I just install RHEL 7 OS on my second Hard disk, is there a way to directly configure the windows Boot loader (bcdedit.exe) to add this RHEL 7 OS installation path?

Question E: Can I install RHEL 7 OS on my second Hard disk together with GRUB Boot loader on this same hard disk and then configure Windows C: drive information here?

Note: Both my 2 HDD are Sata HDD.

Comment: If UEFI hardware generally better to use UEFI installs. But Windows cannot be easily converted, you will have to backup your data & reinstall. Windows only installs in UEFI mode to gpt drives. If BIOS you only install grub to MBR of drive, usually same drive as install, and set BIOS to boot that drive. If UEFI you install to drive, but files go into ESP - efi system partition.  You can use gpt even with BIOS boot with most Linux installs, but need bios_grub partition. Use grub to boot Windows, not Windows to boot grub. Make sure Windows fast start up is off.

Comment: @oldfred I am ok with legacy bios with MBR. My query is that,  I am able to install red hat enterprise Linux 7 on my second HDD which is also MBR partitioned but it is not getting displayed anywhere to choose fwhile booting my PC. As you said, I have disabled fast boot from my uefi bios setting as well as from my windows 10 OS. Still the same issue. I have also heard from somewhere that fast boot is applicable to gpt disk and not to MBR disk.

Comment: Fast boot is an UEFI setting, that is before UEFI knows if booting from MBR or gpt drive. Fast start up is a Windows only setting, not related. If you have legacy/CSM/BIOS boot mode on in UEFI, and grub installed to MBR ot Linux drive, then UEFI should looks for UEFI boot entries, not find any, then look for MBR's with boot files and offer to boot those. Have not installed Red Hat, but grub has to be in MBR of that drive.

Comment: @oldfred I agree with you on fast boot/fast startup...Linux is installed on second hard HDD as boot drive but and this is also MBR partitioned. My Asus motherboard is not able to load Linux and straight away get into windows 10 OS. Any idea and do I need to change any config settings

Comment: Often Windows settings like its fast boot. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Article on UEFI:   https://www.zdnet.com/article/linux-on-your-laptop-heres-what-you-need-to-know-about-uefi-firmware/